# jQuery mouseover functionality not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On hover functionality is not moving perfect. This is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/U4EF8/) and when a mouse is placed over Details* text then whole div color changed to black. But the functionality is not working fine. I want whenever mouse is placed over details text then it should call the hover function but right now its not working fine. Any recommendations?

```
$('#disclaimer').hover(
        function () {
            $('#wrapper').addClass('hovered');
        }, function () {
            $('#wrapper').removeClass('hovered');
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

script :

```
$('#disclaimer').hover(
            function () {
                $('#wrapper').addClass('hover');
            }, function () {
                $('#wrapper').removeClass('hover');
            }
        );
```

style :

```
.hover {
    display : block;
    background-color : black;
}
/* new css */
.hover #Image_Car { display: none; }
.hover #ctaBtn {    display: none; }
.hover #Image_logo {    display: none; }
.hover #headlineText {     display: none; }
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/U4EF8/7/

Comment: thanks but now it is changing too fast and border is visible as well.

Comment: well you have removed easing function its turning black too fast

Comment: well just need to add my class hover into that style where you have implemented the easing..Updated that part

Comment: thanks mate but this one is now working in different way. Maincontainer is turning black then border part is changing its color and that disclaimer* text is invisible. I want to implement the exact effect of my code

Comment: @ user3718016 updated the code.I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: thanks alot i appreciate your efforts but this one is very similar to my original post and if you move your mouse over details text then mouse blinks few times and then you have to move your mouse over other letters of details text and then it seems to work. i was looking for more perfect solution like instead of blinking my mouse cursor when i move it over the text it should call the method

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("#searchput").hover(function() {
     $('#wrapper').addClass("hover");
}, function() {
     $('#wrapper').removeClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: add the your jsfiddle address

Comment: what do you mean by new code. I have have any searchput or cfse_a

Comment: cfse_a is the class name. you can use your own class name at the place of  cfse_a

Comment: thanks but i am using the same code and thats why i am wondering why it is not working smoothly

Comment: i'm using class and you are using id. you try with class

Comment: my friend hovered is a class as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "#disclaimer" )
 .mouseover(function() {
      $('#wrapper').addClass('hovered');
 })
.mouseout(function() {
   $('#wrapper').removeClass('hovered');
  });

 });
```

and my html is :

```
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
  <div id="disclaimer" style="border:1px solid black;">
    hello    
    </div>
```

Here is the working example : http://jsbin.com/heduqesu/2/edit   , you can check in console that class is added and removed on mouse enter and mouse leave event . Hope this helps . Cheers!

Comment: thanks zafus but i am doing the same thing i dont know may be you didnot understand my question. I have already implemented hover effect but when i move my mouse over details text then it should call the hover effect but it is not calling the hover function if i move my mouse continuously over details text then it calls the function

Comment: YOu should use mouseover instead of hover as mouseover(): Fire events for the children of that element.

hover(): Hover actually works with mouseenter and mouseleave without firing for children.  Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

did you already try this ?

```
$('#disclaimer').mouseenter(
    function () {
        $('#wrapper').addClass('hovered');
    }
);
$('#disclaimer').mouseleave(
    function () {
        $('#wrapper').removeClass('hovered');
    }
);
```

or with pure css

```
#disclaimer:hover { 
     //put any attribute on "hovered" class here
}
```

or maybe i don't understand your question enough.